# R raster package no longer reads E00GRID files?

Tags: r, raster, arcgis, rgdal, terra

I updated R and all of my packages recently and am no longer able to read files that previously worked. Specifically, I am trying to read in ArcInfo Exchange grid files (.e00) using the raster package.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know how to fix it? Alternatively, I'd be happy to convert the .e00 files to a geotiff (or other more common format) using a command line program, but can't seem to find one to use (help appreciated!)- the [online converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) I found   doesn't work.

Here's the package versions I'm using and [one of the files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKDcN2PgkBtVN1aticg1EUowqoxiqbam/view?usp=sharing) if anyone wants to try to replicate the error I'm getting:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.5-32  raster_3.5-15 sp_1.5-0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1   tools_4.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.8.3     codetools_0.2-18 grid_4.2.1      
[6] lattice_0.20-45  terra_1.5-34    
> raster("n_tw-2000.e00")
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the E00GRID driver has been removed from GDAL. At the bottom of [this page](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) there is a note that says:

> The following drivers have been retired and moved to the
> https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal-extra-drivers repository: BPG, E00GRID,
> EPSILON, IGNFHeightASCIIGrid, NTv1

And if you follow the hyperlink, you can see that for this driver to work you need to use software built with a version of the GDAL library that is below 3.3.

I can confirm that this used to work. With `rgdal` version 1.5-23 (as built by CRAN for windows):

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp
raster("n_tw-2000.e00")
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 775, 1440, 1116000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 4134.354, 4134.354  (x, y)
#extent     : -2950369, 3003101, 115686.8, 3319811  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : c:/Users/rhijm/Downloads/n_tw-2000.e00 
#names      : n_tw.2000 
#values     : 0.9885814, 58.99333  (min, max)
```

And the reason this works is that GDAL is below 3.3:

```
library(rgdal)
#rgdal: version: 1.5-23, (SVN revision 1121)
#Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
#Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29
```

I can also open the file with current `terra` and older version of GDAL:

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.5.48
gdal()
#[1] "2.2.3"

rast("n_tw-2000.e00")
#class       : SpatRaster
#dimensions  : 775, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 4134.354, 4134.354  (x, y)
#extent      : -2950369, 3003101, 115686.8, 3319811  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=0 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=45.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=-96 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
#source      : n_tw-2000.e00
#name        : n_tw-2000
#min value   : 0.9885814
#max value   :  58.99333
```

What you could do, if you are on windows, is install an old (binary) version that you download [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/)

Or, if you are on linux, build `terra` (or `raster` and `rgdal`) in a (linux) docker, after installing GDAL 3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation! I suspected as much, but didn't know how to find the answer.